# Django REST Framework: change field names

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Django application provides readonly api access to the users of the site. I created a user profile model and use it in the serializer of the user model:

Model:

```
# + standard User Model

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('display_name',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    userprofile_set = UserProfileSerializer(many=False, label='userprofile')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'userprofile_set')
```

This works but the field `userprofile_set` looks ugly. Is it possible to change the field name?

Answer (score 2):

To complement your answer, you can also make use of relationships' related names:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profiles')
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

that way you can also use this in your code:

```
user = User.objects.last() #some user
user.profiles.all() #UserProfiles related to this user, in a queryset
user.profiles.last() #the last UserProfile instance related to this user.
```

May I recommend that you turn that ForeignKey into a OneToOneField? that way an user can have one and just one user profile, and you don't need to establish uniqueness:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I can name the variable `userprofile_set` as I like. First I tested the name `userprofile` which conflicted. If I name the field `profile` it works. :)

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(many=False, label='userprofile')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'profile')
```